# Looking for the name of a book from my childhood

Tags: story-identification

When I was a kid I read a book about an alien girl who came to live on earth with her dad. He started dating a human and she had a daughter the girl became friends with. The girl talks about body surfing a lot and how she like becomes one with the water. She also talks about her dead mom. When they come they pick names and I think her dad picks something to do with coke or Pepsi because he likes the drink. I'm looking for the name of this book. The book name might be the girls name but I don't remember what that was.

Comment: Read it when you were a kid? So that would have been around 1945? Or more like 2013? You see, it might help somebody find your book if they knew about when you read it, but we don't know how old you are. Is the story set in the present or in the future? Is there anything science-fictiony about it besides the alien? Are there lots of aliens on earth, or just this girl and her dad? Why are they on earth?

Comment: It would have been the early 2000s and it talks a lot about her alien speicies but you only hear about her family and home planet. t

Answer (score 6):

That's [Stepsister from Planet Weird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepsister_from_Planet_Weird), book by [Francess Lanz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francess_Lantz) (1996), [Movie from 2000](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0250754/). The name the alien dad choses is "Cosmo Cola".